# RecognizeAsync() doesn't work but Recognize() does, why?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, speech

Im trying to have my windows forms program to continuously listen to my microphone to detect speech and then display that information on the gui.
Here is my SpeechListener class:

```
{
    public class SpeechListener
    {

        GUI gui;

        public SpeechListener(GUI gui) { this.gui = gui; }

        public void StartListening() {

            gui.setLabel("speech activated");

            // Create an in-process speech recognizer for the en-US locale.  
            using (
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
              new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
            {

                // Create and load a dictation grammar.  
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.  
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

                // Configure input to the speech recognizer.  
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.  
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            }


        }

        // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.  
        public void Recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
           //this is where i want to get
            gui.setLabel("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

This class is instantiated and StartListening() is called from a form class (my gui).
I never reach the method that handles the SpeechRecognized event. However when i change

recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

to

recognizer.Recognize();

the speech detection works (but only once, and it freezes my gui). Why doesn't the async method work?
I've used this same code on a console program and it works perfectly.

Comment: Remove the `using` block (you can dispose of `recognizer` when you're done with it), add `recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate()` before `recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new DictationGrammar());`. I suggest to add a handler to `AudioStateChanged`.

Comment: You aren't using RecognizeAsync properly (where is the 'await').  You are basically starting a new task and then never waiting for it to finish.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! Removing the using block solved it.